# No response from AcquireTokenAsync with "user_impersonation" token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, adal

I've got a site based Web App which authenticates users via AAD login.  A successful login will redirect the user back to the app with the access token (this part is all done using adal_angular.js/adal.js)

The token is then passed to a site based api which gets a new token on behalf of the user to call a downstream api as per this example (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof)  So far so good.

The downstream api, repeats this process to get another token to call another api further downstream.  Here is where the problem is.

When calling AcquireTokenAsync() here, I get no response from the call whatsoever.
***Edit:  No response means that I get no response from Azure AAD, using Fiddler to trace the HTTP traffic, I'm not seeing any URLs being hit as part of the AcquireTokenAsync call ***

I noticed that the token I'm using at this point is now a "user_impersonation" token, where as the token received by the site based api is not.  Is this significant?

Should this architecture be supported?

Comment: This scenario is supported and you should be able to get this working.  One complication that can come up w/ multi-tenant cases is the user will not have consented for the middle tier service 2 to consent to the final downstream api.  If this is in fact the issue, you can do admin consent from the middle tier 1 time w/ `prompt=admin_consent` or have the middle tier service 2 ask for consent on the client app.  Either way, you should use fiddler and check if there is no response from AzureAD, or if there is an error coming back and edit your post with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem here was my own use of async methods in my webapi.  If you are calling async methods in your webapi, you need to mark your own web api methods as async.  If ASP.Net doesn't know that you want to call async methods in your controller, it can cause deadlocks.  (A good explanation here:  http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-o...
You should never use .Result on your async methods in a web api.